# Cloudfront with S3 static site hosting responds with 504 error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I've setup S3 + Cloudfront to host a static website using a subdomain provided by Namecheap, but when navigating to the Cloudfront URL, or domain URL, AWS responds with a 504: "The request could not be satisfied" error.

The steps I've completed are:

1. Setup the S3 bucket to have Static website hosting: Enabled with the hosting type set to "Bucket hosting". The bucket is `Publicly accessible`.
2. Setup a Cloudfront distribution with its origin domain set to `[bucket name].s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com` which has completed deployment.
3. Set `[subdomain].[domain].io` as an alternate domain name within the Cloudfront distribution.
4. Assigned a Custom SSL certificate to my distribution that has a status of "Issued" from AWS Certificate Manager for my custom domain `[subdomain].[domain].io`
5. Setup a CNAME within NameCheap so that `[subdomain]` points to `[abc123].cloudfront.net.` which has propagated (confimed by whatsmydns.net)

I'm new to Cloudfront + S3 hosting and trying to skill up, but not hosting in general (I usually use EC2 with either Apache or NGINX).

How can I resolve the 504 error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that I was using `[bucket name].s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com` like the tutorials I'm using take special note to specify. Nowadays it seems you should use `[bucket name].s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com` instead.

Once I made the above update and the distribution was deployed everything started working.

Comment: That's because you're connecting directly to the route and not the website endpoint. And it depends if you're origin resource is s3 or custom, connecting directly to the bucket and not the website url is fine for the s3 origin, but for custom origins you must connect to the website url. @leoandreotti do you know what permissions should be defined for connecting cloudfront to a bucket without using OAI?

Answer (score 11):

my solution to this problem in terraform is with :
origin_protocol_policy = "http-only"

because s3 static website endpoint is on http, so if you choose "https-only"
it will give 504 error.

Answer (score 2):

This error 504: "The request could not be satisfied" usually means that the cloudfront distribution can’t connect to the configured source. Are you able to access your system using the website URL directly without CF?

Have you set cloudfront, during the distribution creation, to be the only allowed to access the bucket by accident?
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-access-to-amazon-s3/

Everything makes me believe that your bucket is not accessible even if you set the website hosting feature.

Answer (score 1):

Two things solved my issue:

1. Added s3:GetObjectVersion action to the public permission for s3

   ```
        {
        "Sid": "Allow-Public-Access-To-Bucket",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectVersion"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::ops.freeway-camper-tests.com/*"
    }
   ```
2. Ensure that NO custom headers are defined in the origin